# AutoMapper for IEnumerable<EFEntityClass> to IEnumerable<ClassViewModel>

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, automapper

I have a situation where I had to change the signature from `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable` and the AutoMapper's extension `.ProjectTo()` method stops working. I need an alternate to it and what mapping changes do I need to make, if any?

```
public class PersonService : IPersonService
{
    private readonly IPlaygroundBiRepository _repository;
    private readonly IMapper                 _autoMapper;

    public PersonService(IPlaygroundBiRepository repository, IMapper autoMapper)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _autoMapper = autoMapper;
    }

    public async Task<PersonViewModel> GetPersonByIdAsync(int id) => new PersonViewModel(await _repository.GetPersonByIdAsync(id));

    public IEnumerable<PersonViewModel> GetPersons() => _repository.GetPersons().ProjectTo<PersonViewModel>(_autoMapper.ConfigurationProvider);       
}
```

Here is how AutoMapper is setup in infrastructure project:

```
namespace DesignTracker.Application.AutoMapper
{
    public class AutoMapperConfiguration
    {
        public static MapperConfiguration RegisterMappings()
        {
            return new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                // cfg.AddProfile(new ViewModelToDomainProfile());
                cfg.AddProfile(new DomainToViewModelProfile());
            });
        }
    }

    public class DomainToViewModelProfile : Profile
    {
        public DomainToViewModelProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you have a look into `AutoMapper.Collection` (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection)?

Comment: I'm there right now. I'm just figuring out how this will work out in my Clean Arch./CQRS